# I'm Facing Truble in Fetching Image in Laravel Nova for Products Resource

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-nova

I am using Image Field in Laravel Nova "use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Image;" and Hare is the inside of field function "Image::make('Product Image', 'image')->help('Upload a Product image')->path('/uploads')->maxWidth(400)->prunable()->creationRules('required'),". it showing ! sign instead of Product Image. Picture is Successfully moving to Storage Uploads and Storage is Linked to Public.

I have tried the Following Code "Image::make('Product Image', 'image')->help('Upload a Product image')->path('/uploads')->maxWidth(400)->prunable()->creationRules('required'),. But image is not Appearing on the Screen. Picture is Successfully moving to Storage Uploads and Storage is Linked to Public.